# Did somebody encounter this error on Android P Error "Package com...... Persistent apps are not updateable."

Tags: android, adb, android-9.0-pie

when I try to update an app (persistent app + launcher) on an Android P device that has the same app installed (App included in the Firmware as system app) I get the following error:
"Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package X is a persistent app. Persistent apps are not updateable.]"
Did you encounter this error before? 
PS. this does not happen on pre PIE devices.

Comment: Yes I get this - no solution yet